# .htaccess Rewrite Rules, friendly URLs + redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using .htaccess to take URLs that look like:

```
/index.php?page=2
```

and rewrite them to, for example:

```
/contact-us
```

I want to do two things:

When loading /contact-us, show page /index.php?page=2 but keep the friendly URL. I know this looks something like:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ "index\.php\?page\=2" [L]
```

Which does work ok. But now I also want people who navigate to /index.php?page=2 to end up on /contact-us - how do I achieve this as a 301 redirect in combination with the friendly URL rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using quotes and escapes in target portion of your rewrite rule.  The target portion is not a regular expression. That can simply look like:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /index.php?page=2 [L]
```

To redirect the index.php?page=2 you will need to do the following.  This rule MUST be before the rule above or you will get in rewrite loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=2$
RewriteRule .* /contact-us [R=301,L]
```

Here you are setting two rewrite conditions: that the page is `/index.php` and that the query string is `page=2` (and only `page=2`).  The `R=301` flag will force an external rewrite to /contact-us and also send and HTTP 301 header.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php?page=12$ /addiction-treatment-recovery-programs [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^addiction-treatment-recovery-programs$ index.php?page=12 [L]`  Does this look correct?

Comment: @SarahBee See my latest update.  I didn't show rewrite rule correctly initially.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=12$  
RewriteRule .* /addiction-treatment-recovery-programs [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^edgewood.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.edgewood.ca$
RewriteRule ^addiction-treatment-recovery-programs$ index.php?page=12 [L]`

Sorry I'm a bit of a fail formatting with mini-markdown. I've got this and a redirect loop now. Also it's redirecting with the query string (/addiction-treatment-recovery-programs?page=12)

Comment: Ok I see I had to add the question mark to prevent the query string, but still unsure how to avoid this redirect loop.

Comment: @SarahBee You should update your OP with your latest code.  Hard to tell what you are doing.  I can't see from what you have shown what would cause redirect loop.  I am not sure why you have those rewrite conditions for the second rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=2[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ contact-us? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ index.php?page=2 [L,QSA,NC]
```